# Android zip Structure

Tags: java, android, zip, structure

I have a created a directory with some images stored in it. Now, to zip it as a single .zip file, I used the following code :

```
private static void zipDir(String zipFileName, String dir) throws Exception {
    File dirObj = new File(dir);
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(newFileOutputStream(zipFileName));
    addDir(dirObj, out);
    out.close();
}

static void addDir(File dirObj, ZipOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    File[] files = dirObj.listFiles();
    byte[] tmpBuf = new byte[1024];

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
        addDir(files[i], out);
        continue;
     }
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
     System.out.println(" Adding: " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
     out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
     int len;
     while ((len = in.read(tmpBuf)) > 0) {
        out.write(tmpBuf, 0, len);
     }
  out.closeEntry();
  in.close();
}
```

}

I obtained this code from the following source : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Makingazipfileofdirectoryincludingitssubdirectoriesrecursively.htm

However instead of only adding the pictures in the zip file, it add all the parent directories too.
For example instead of having all the pictures inside abc.zip, all files are created inside the following path : Intruder_Pictures.zip\storage\emulated\0\Pictures\ABC Pictures\

Is there any way by which I could just have the pictures directly inside the zip.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instanciate your ZipEntry with the filename, not the path.

```
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(files[i].getName()));
```